# Insert data into temp table from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a database and need to create a temp table. Then insert data from multiple tables.
Here is a task:

[image: screenshot]

And here is a diagram:

[image: diagram]

I tried to use joins but it creates duplicates (e.g. one companion for all films). Just don't understand how to use `JOIN` correctly with multiple tables

Answer (score 1):

A few left joins with a group by and string aggregation could work.

But string aggregation is dependent on the DBMS.

MySql 8.0 has [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

For example in MySql 8.0:

```
SELECT 
episode.EpisodeNumber,
episode.Title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT companion.CompanionName ORDER BY companion.CompanionName SEPARATOR ', ') AS CompanionNames,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT enemy.EnemyName ORDER BY enemy.EnemyName SEPARATOR ', ') AS EnemyNames
INTO tempEpisodeCompanionEnemy
FROM tblEpisode AS episode
LEFT JOIN tblEpisodeCompanion AS ec
  ON ec.EpisodeId = episode.EpisodeId
LEFT JOIN tblCompanion AS companion
  ON companion.CompanionId = ec.CompanionId
LEFT JOIN tblEpisodeEnemy AS ee
  ON ee.EpisodeId = episode.EpisodeId
LEFT JOIN tblEnemy AS enemy
  ON enemy.EnemyId = ee.EnemyId
GROUP BY episode.EpisodeNumber, episode.Title
```

Oracle DB has [LISTAGG](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)

```
....
LISTAGG(companion.CompanionName,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY companion.CompanionName) AS CompanionNames,
....
```

Sql Server 2017 has [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)

```
...
STRING_AGG(companion.CompanionName,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY companion.CompanionName ASC) AS CompanionNames,
...
```

PostgreSql has [STRING_AGG](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/)

```
...
STRING_AGG(distinct companion.CompanionName,', ' ORDER BY companion.CompanionName ASC) AS CompanionNames,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First create temp table with fields episodenumber,episodetitle,companion name. Later insert like this query below

```
insert into temp values((select episodenumber from tblepisode),(select episodetitle from tblepisode),(select companionName from tblcompanion),(select enemyname from tblenemy) );
```